# Input using command line arguments

Tags: ruby

Define a class Account with three three attributes "name","account_no" & "balance". Name and Balance should be set when creating an object of Account class, account_number should be auto increment. This Account class must have two methods, deposit() and withdraw().

Your program should take three arguments
1. customer one
2. customer two
3. transaction amount

Input Format:
customer_name1:account_balance1 customer_name2:account_balance2 transfer:transaction_amount

I am trying to get input using ARGV, but not sure how to get input in format --
ABC:2000 XYZ:3000 transfer:200

Any suggestions ?

Comment: You're being downvoted because you haven't shown any code samples that you've tried, and this is a homework assignment

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it's a good idea to use program arguments for that kind of test (I would use a file with all the possible transations).

If you still want to use ARGV when you call your ruby program like this : `ruby prog_name.rb ABC:2000 XYZ:3000 transfer:200` ARGV will look like this : `["ABC:2000", "XYZ:3000", "transfer:200"]`
So

- ARGV[0] is "customer_name1:account_balance1" (use split(':') & to_i to get the right values)
- ARGV[1] is "customer_name2:account_balance2"
- ARGV[2] is "transfer:transaction_amount"

---

My suggestion for the file usage involve the `gets` function. Basically you'll create a file that contains the following :

```
create_account ABC
create_account XYZ
deposit 2000 ABC
deposit 3000 XYZ
transfer 200 ABC XYZ
```

With this data you know what you're doing and what function you'll call, the program using the Account class will have this structure :

```rb
require "account" # I'm supposing your $LOAD_PATH is correctly set

while (line = gets)
  command, *params = line.split(' ')
  case command
  when 'create_account'
    # Create an account with name = params.first
  when 'deposit'
    # Deposit params.first.to_i in account with name params[1]
  when 'transfer'
    # Make sure account with name params[1] has params.first.to_i in its balance
    # Withdraw params.first.to_i from account with name params[1]
    # Deposit params.first.to_i in account with name params[2]
  else
    puts "Unknown command #{command} in line #{line}"
  end
end
```

This way you'll only have to call `ruby program_name.rb dataset.txt` and it'll process all the line of dataset.txt. You can create various dataset to make sure your account manager does the right thing. (So you'll need to make transfert methods & find account method in a AccountManager class).

Comment: Thanks ! it was nice suggestion.